# How do I create a infopath form with hidden columns that appear once submitted to an approver

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I am required to create a Infopath form which does not show the area for digital signatures to the requestor but gets sent to the approver who see's the area for digital signatures.

For example:
1)User loads form
2)The form the user sees only contains check boxes and no digital signature fields.
3)The user pushes submit
4)The form is sent to the approver via a sharepoint workflow
5)The approver sees the check boxes with the signature box
6)The form is approver and sent back to the requestor who can now see the signatures

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Views in InfoPath to achieve this.  Here is one of many write-ups from Microsoft on the subject:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-HA101732801.aspx